Proving Quine's notion that identity belongs to logic within type-constrained proof assistants
I'm having difficulty generalizing the following proof to permit predicates of any finite arity.
Consider the following axioms of identity consistent with W. V. O. Quine's argument that relative identity belongs to logic rather than to set theory:
Axiom 1: Identity(s,x,x)
Axiom 2: Identity(s,x,y)<=>Identity(s,y,x)
Axiom 3: Identity(s,x,y) and Identity(s,y,z) => Identity(s,x,z)

Here s is a standard language and the variables x, y and z are meant to follow the principle of substitutivity within that language's predicates.
An example from Quine's "The Scope of Logic":

The method of definition is evident from the following example.
Consider a standard language whose lexicon of predicates con sists of
a one-place predicate 'A', two two-place predicates 'B' and 'C' and a
three-place predicate 'D'. We then define 'x = y' as short for:
(3) Ax ≡ Ay. yz (Bz ≡ xBzy. Bxz ≡ Byz. Czx ≡ Czy. Cxz ≡ Cyz. z'
(Dzz'x ≡ Dzz'y. Dzxz' ≡ Dzyz' Dxzz' ≡ Dyzz') ).
Note the plan: the exhaustion of combinations. What 'x = y' tells us,
according to this definition, is that the objects x and y are
indistinguishable by the four predicates; that they are
indistinguishable from each other even in their relations to any other
objects z and z', insofar as these relations are expressed in simple
sentences. Now it can be shown that, when (3) holds, the objects x and
y will be indistinguishable by any sentences whatever, simple or not,
that can be phrased in the language.
It may happen that the objects intended as values of the variables of
quantification are not completely distinguishable from one another by
the four predicates. When this happens, (3) fails to define genuine
identity. Still, such failure remains unobservable from within the
language; (3) is as good as identity from that vantage point. It is
readily seen that the axiom (1), 'x = x', is a truth purely of the
logic of quantification and truth functions when '=' is defined by
(3). It can be shown further that (2) becomes a valid schema of
quantification theory.¹
This method of defining or simulating identity depends on finitude of
the lexicon of predicates, since the analogue of (3) for  an
infinitude of predicates would never end.
¹The proof follows the lines of Mathematical Logic, § 18.

One might hope that types would assist the constructive proof by permitting something like a "standard language" type and, indeed, one may almost achieve this in Isabelle by simply defining a type predicate and then a type predicate set:
theory IdentityTheory
imports Main
begin

(* Assume we have a type 'a Predicate that represents predicates over type 'a.
   PredicateCollection is a collection of such predicates. *)
type_synonym 'a Predicate = "'a ⇒ bool"
type_synonym 'a PredicateCollection = "'a Predicate set"

(* Now, let's define Identity in a way that's polymorphic over the type 'a. *)
axiomatization
  where Identity1: "∀S x::'a. Identity (S::'a PredicateCollection) x x" and
        Identity2: "∀S x y::'a. Identity (S::'a PredicateCollection) x y ⟷ Identity S y x" and
        Identity3: "∀S x y z::'a. Identity (S::'a PredicateCollection) x y ∧ Identity S y z ⟶ Identity S x z"

(* QuineIdentity definition here, making sure it matches the polymorphic nature of the axioms. *)
definition QuineIdentity :: "'a PredicateCollection ⇒ 'a ⇒ 'a ⇒ bool" where
  "QuineIdentity S x y ≡ ∀p∈S. p x = p y"

(* Now, prove that QuineIdentity satisfies the identity axioms *)

lemma QuineIdentity_satisfies_Axiom1: "∀S x. QuineIdentity S x x"
  unfolding QuineIdentity_def
  by auto

lemma QuineIdentity_satisfies_Axiom2: "∀S x y. QuineIdentity S x y ⟷ QuineIdentity S y x"
  unfolding QuineIdentity_def
  by auto

lemma QuineIdentity_satisfies_Axiom3: "∀S x y z. (QuineIdentity S x y ∧ QuineIdentity S y z) ⟶ QuineIdentity S x z"
  unfolding QuineIdentity_def
  by auto
end

However, notice that this only works because it assumes all predicates are properties (ie: predicates of arity 1).

Axiom 3 seems strange. The right-to-left implication, plus axiom 1, makes the relation total.

That was my mistake.  I've edited to replace "<=>" with "=>" in Axiom 3.

It's still a biimplication in the code snippet. Anyway, for the sake of this exercise, I would expect a binary relation R to yield a predicate like x ↦ (∀z. Rxz) ∧ (∀z. Rzx), or equivalently one predicate for each conjunct. I don't know Isabelle, so I can't turn that into a working answer, but that would be my first thing to try.

I only went to Isabelle because the other proof assistants seemed even more restrictive  when it came to permitting proofs without type assumptions.  Or am I misunderstanding how those impact generating operations for all combinations of arbitrary substitutions and arities?

May I ask, are you doing this for historical value? Also, the definition of QuineIdentity looks like some form of Leibniz identity.

There are two senses in which it is for historical value.  The first is the obvious sense.  The second is that this is motivated by my (nascent) attempt to formalize a 2006 paper titled "Three-place Identity" in which my late colleague, Tom Etter, proposed a radically different foundation for mathematical expressivity.
https://groups.io/g/lawsofform/files/Boundary%20Institute/Tom%20Etter%20Papers/threeplaceidentity.pdf
I salvaged Tom's papers upon his death.  A tragically unfinished companion paper, "Membership and Identity" does, indeed, purports to generalize Lieibniz.

Here's the relevant excerpt from M&I:
Leibniz, like everyone else in his time and most people today, regarded the identity predicate as absolute, and he claimed that universal substitutivity is its defining feature. However, if we take identity to be relative, we can think of Leibniz' law as only defining substitutivity at one free variable.

Perhaps this is just me, but I'm not exactly sure what the question is here. Is it like: how do you write something similar to $\sum_{n:ℕ} ((\mathsf{Fin}\ n → a) → \mathsf{bool})$ in Isabelle?
